# Java socket server not responding

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I am getting started with java sockets just out of inquisitiveness.

I wrote a small piece of code, a server and a client.

The server accepts a string and converts it to upper case and returns to the client.

I want the server to be able to handle multiple clients and have a persistent connection.

Here is the server code :

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {

    private ServerSocket listener;
    private ArrayList<Socket> clients;

    public Server() throws IOException{
        clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
        listener = new ServerSocket(7575);
    }

    public Server(int port) throws IOException{
        clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
        listener = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void start() throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        Thread one = new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                while (true){
                    Socket socket = null;
                    try {
                        socket = listener.accept();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (socket.isConnected()){
                        try {
                            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                        } catch (SocketException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        clients.add(socket);
                        System.out.println(socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread two = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    while (true){
                        work();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        one.start();
        two.start();

        one.join();
        two.join();

        stop();
    }

    private void stop() throws IOException{
        listener.close();
    }

    private void work() throws IOException{
        if (clients.size() == 0){
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++){
            Socket socket = clients.get(i);
            if (!socket.isClosed()){
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                String data = br.readLine();
                if (data == null) continue;
                out.println(data.toUpperCase());
            }
            else{
                clients.remove(socket);
            }
        }
    }
}

package entry;

import java.io.IOException;

import server.Server;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Server server = new Server();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the client :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.110", 7575);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while (true){
            System.out.println("\n\nEnter a string : ");
            String inp = br.readLine();
            if (inp.equals("quit")) break;
            pr.println(inp);
            System.out.println("The response is : " + sr.readLine());
        }
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Strange thing here is when I set a breakpoint in the server code and step through the code in eclipse, the code is working exactly as expected i.e I am getting the response in the client.

But when I run it directly in eclipse, I am not getting the response in the client.

Cannot understand what is going wrong.

*Edit*

I seem to have fixed the issue.

Here is the code snippet :

```
Thread two = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    while (true){
                        Thread.sleep(1000); //This is the added line
                        work();
                    }
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
```

But I am still confused about what made the timing difference. 
Is there any cleaner way to achieve this ?

Comment: Where's your `main` method in Server??

Comment: added main method. just didn't add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem with a different approach.

Here is the new Approach:

ServerHandler.java :

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ServerHandler extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    private ArrayList<Socket> clients;

    public ServerHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException{
        this.socket = socket;
        clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();
        if (!clients.contains(socket)){
            clients.add(this.socket);
            System.out.println(this.socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (true){
            if (clients.isEmpty()) break;
            String str = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++){
                Socket socket = clients.get(i);
                if (socket.isClosed()){
                    clients.remove(socket);
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    str = in.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.println(str.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java [for running the server] :

```
package entry;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

import server.ServerHandler;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7575);
        try{
            while (true){
                new ServerHandler(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are trying to achieve multiple clients connecting to a server? If so, then there is definitely much better way to achieve this

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do exactly that. I modified my code to get it done with this approach. Could you please point me to other better approach you were talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Here we go.I don't understand the use of `Arraylist` for maintaining Connections unless You are handling the messy details for each `Client`.
The most used or prefered approach for handling multiple clients at a time can be understood in terms of an example:

### Server.java

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.IOException;

class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try( ServerSocket ss =  new ServerSocket(3333)) { // try with resources
            new ServerThread(ss.accept()).start();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just defined a Class that will listen for Client connections, and as soon a request is made to the server it will start a Thread which is defined in the next class. A point to be noted here is the use of `Try-with-Resources` block. Any class that implements the `Closeable` interface can be enclosed within this try statement. The try-with-resources automatically handles closing of streams or connections for me. This means, you remove all your redundant `try-catch` blocks from your code and use this `try` instead.

Now,

### ServerThread.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    Socket s = null;

    public ServerThread(Socket s) {
        super("ServerThread");
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        try( PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                            BufferedReader write = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("In Server");
            String in, out;
            while ((in = stream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Msg 4m client: " + in);
                if(in.equals("bye"))
                    break;
                out = write.readLine();
                pw.println(out);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Observe the `try-with-resources` statement over here, We can initialize multiple Connections/Input-Output Streams here, All of the opened connection will automatically be closed as soon as the compiler returns from `try` statement.Also, Observe the `while` statement, it will keep on running until the client is sending messages, and will quit if the message is `"bye"`.

Finally, a Client program that sends request to the server.

### Client.java

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try( Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3333); 
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true); 
                    BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())); 
                        BufferedReader write = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ) {
            System.out.println("In Client");
            String in;
            while ((in = write.readLine()) != null) {                
                pw.println(in);
                if(in.equals("bye"))
                    break;
                System.out.println("Msg 4m server: " + stream.readLine());
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice, the `while` Statement here, it will loop until the user is entering messages, and if the message is "bye", it will quit.Rest of the program can be easily understood from above explanation.

Comment: Yup. I've used exactly the same approach. See my code below. The reason I've used an ArrayList is, I plan to write a simple chat server. So I need to maintain the client list, so that I can send message from one client to another. If there is more elegant way of doing that, please let me know! :)

Comment: This method is suggested by `Ora Developers` since it uses Threading concepts efficiently and utilizes the power of `Threads` and `try-with-resources` to minimize the complexity involved. Only problem in your code is that, it is difficult to read and make use of redundant `try-catch` statements. Rest I cannot think of any other problems :) Be sure to upvote and accept an answer and close the thread if you got your answer.